# wp_ajax function did not call

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to use for the second time the hook wp_ajax to call a php method from a Class inside my js script. I did it one time with success but this time, it does not work. I don't know why.

Context : I do this in an addon, not in my main plugin.

I did all these following steps :

**Add my function in my class *FooClass***

```
namespace Namespace\Common;

class FooClass{

    public static function getItems()... 

    public static function getItemsByAjax() {
        error_log( 'getItemsByAjax' );
        $f_options = self::getItems( $_POST[ 'foo_type' ] );
        $json = json_encode( $f_options );
        echo $json;
        wp_die();
    }

}
```

**Init this function inside another Class called on an admin page**

```
class OtherClass{

    public function __construct(){
         add_action('wp_ajax_getItemsByAjax', array( 'Namespace\Common\FooClass', 'getItemsByAjax' ) );
    }

}
```

**Usage in my jQueryScript**

```
jQuery( function($) {

   $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.my-button').click(function() {
             var data = {
                'action': 'getItemsByAjax',
                'foo_type' : 'x'
             };
             $.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse( response );
                console.dir( jsonObj );
             });
        });
   });
```

});

*getItemsByAjax()* is never called. What could I have forgotten ?

Comment: Maybe wp_ajax_nopriv? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)

Comment: I'm using for the back-end, not the front-end.

Comment: What browser console shows on request? Is it returns 0 or something else?

Comment: My browser console return nothing, and the error_log write nothing in the debug log file.

Comment: Use Network tab in Google Chrome to see XHR request on posting. So if the request is not sending, it javascript related question, otherwise wordpress related

Comment: When I click on the button, I can see only the admin-ajax.php call in XHR tab ( Firefox for me ;-) )

Comment: I saw the xhr response : it returns 0. I have a 404 reponse.

Comment: Where do you initiate `OtherClass`

Comment: Have you considered instead using a REST API endpoint? It's a much easier to use API. e.g. if you'd done something wrong the REST API would have told you rather than failing silently, and none of the gotchas of `nopriv` etc

Comment: If you only see 0 as response, that means your action was not hooked on that request. Note that it is a separate http request from the one that loaded your admin page, so make sure you are actually hooking the ajax handler on the ajax request.

Comment: @czerspalace I init `Otherclass` in the construct function of an other class C which is init in the addon main class.`Otherclass` is called because it is the class to show the admin page and it is correctly displayed.

Comment: @Milo, I can imagine it's a hooking problem. My question is what could I forgotten to hook correctly this function. Maybe, my calling is too late... I do not know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, and some help inside the comments, I detect the right problem :

> if xhr response returns 0 means that the ajax function does not be hooked.

The solution in my case was to init my addon classes with a right hook like [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289112/how-to-init-an-addon-correctly-after-the-main-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found the problem in your code.
You've forgotten \ on namespace path.

```
class OtherClass{

    public function __construct(){
         add_action('wp_ajax_getItemsByAjax', array( '\Namespace\Common\FooClass', 'getItemsByAjax' ) );
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Same result. It's not the solution. I already use wp_ajax without \  in my main plugin and that works perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure that your class loaded in your code? If you are using composer autoload, you should regenerate autoloading paths

Comment: I'm sure my class is loaded because I use it before to display HTML on this same admin page.